# How send File and File Path from C# Controller to the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sending File and and file path that are both List from controller to the MVC view:

This is my Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Help()
{

    var releaseNoteFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ReleaseNotes"));

    List<string> month = new List<string>();
    foreach (var releaseNoteFile in releaseNoteFiles)
    {
        month.Add(new Regex("([^A-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]*)").Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(releaseNoteFile).Split('.').Last()).Groups[2].Value);
    }
    ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth = month;
    ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles = releaseNoteFiles;

    return View();
}
```

and this is how show it in the View:

```
   @foreach (var item in ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth)
        {              
           <a href="(ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles as string[]).Where(x => x.Contains(item)).FirstOrDefault()"> @item</a>
            <br />
        }
```

This is the output I am expecting:

```
OCT - (Link to the file)
NOV - (Link to the file)
Dec - (Link to the file)
```

when I am Hardcoding the path like this, it is working:

```
 href="~/Content/ReleaseNotes/Release Notes 1.104.0_August102021.pdf"
```

But when I try to access it dynamically not sure how to write a path to the File, this line is not working correctly:

```
 href="(ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles as string[]).Where(x => x.Contains(item)).FirstOrDefault()">
```

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath` returns the file path to the drive, for example `E://projectfolder/content/...` And do not use this address in the url.

add this line your code and set in `ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles = filePath;`

```
List<string> filePath = releaseNoteFiles.Select(a => string.Format("{0}/{1}", "~/Content/ReleaseNotes", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a))).ToList();
```

full code

```
public ActionResult Help()
{

    var releaseNoteFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ReleaseNotes"));

    List<string> month = new List<string>();
    List<string> filePath = releaseNoteFiles.Select(a => string.Format("{0}/{1}", "~/Content/ReleaseNotes", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a))).ToList();
    
    foreach (var releaseNoteFile in releaseNoteFiles)
    {
        month.Add(new Regex("([^A-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]*)").Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(releaseNoteFile).Split('.').Last()).Groups[2].Value);
    }
    ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth = month;
    ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles = filePath;

    return View();
}
```

Or use :

```
public ActionResult Help()
{

    var releaseNoteFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ReleaseNotes"));

    ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth = releaseNoteFiles
                          .Select(a => new Regex("([^A-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]*)").Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a).Split('.').Last()).Groups[2].Value).ToList();
    ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles = releaseNoteFiles.Select(a => string.Format("{0}/{1}", "~/Content/ReleaseNotes", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a))).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

And change view to :

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth)
{  
    string url = string.Empty;
    if(ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    {
        url = (ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles as string[]).Where(x => x.Contains(item)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    
    <a href="@url"> @item</a>
    <br />
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added this code to the controller but the code in View is not working, what should I have in href=""

Comment: Modify your view code. I put the view code in response

Comment: Thank you @Meysam Asadi, getting This error:Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source on the string url = .... in view

Comment: Usually such an error should not be given. ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles is probably null

Comment: it has value when I debug

Comment: use if(ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))